# Is there a way to decompose a quantum circuit into layers?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, quantum-volume

For example, if take the following circuit as the input (either QASM or Qiskit):

```
qreg q[2];
creg c[2];

x q[1];
h q[0];
h q[1];
cx q[0],q[1];
h q[0];
measure q[0] -> c[0];
measure q[1] -> c[1];
```

[image]

The expected output will be:

```
layer[0] = [H [q0], X [q1]]
layer[1] = [H [q1]]
layer[2] = [cnot [q0] [q1]]
layer[3] = [H [q0]]
layer[4] = [measure [q0]]
layer[5] = [measure [q1]]
```

Is there a Qiskit function to achieve this? If not, suggestions to implement this task are also welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: The issue is that the decomposition is not unique. Layers 0 and 1 can be either those you mentioned or `layer[0] = [X [q1]]` and  `layer[1] = [H [q0], H [q1]]`. Also note that you should put identity operators to *empty places* in the circuit, i.e. your layer 1 should be `layer[1] = [I q[0], H [q1]]`

Comment: @MartinVesely Thanks! Yes that's a great point. I guess only CNOT will clearly divide different layers between a bunch of single-qubit gates.

Comment: Yes, or any controlled or multi-controlled gate.

Comment: Just one note. Imagine that you have several controlled gates in row and one single-qubit gate on a qubit below the controlled gates, then it is also ambiguous under which controlled gate to place the single-qubit one.

Comment: That is also true, seems like I need to define some scheduling policy first...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can decompose a quantum circuit into layers using [`DAGCircuit.layers()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.dagcircuit.DAGCircuit.layers.html) method:

```
from qiskit.converters import circuit_to_dag, dag_to_circuit
from IPython.display import display

dag = circuit_to_dag(circ)
for layer in dag.layers():
    layer_as_circuit = dag_to_circuit(layer['graph'])
    display(layer_as_circuit.draw('mpl'))
```

where `circ` is a `QuantumCircuit`. The output will be:

[image]

`DAGCircuit.layers()` method constructs the layers using a greedy algorithm.

You can also break down your circuit into layers based on some scheduling policy. In the following example we apply an "as late as possible" ([ALAP](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.transpiler.passes.ALAPScheduleAnalysis.html)) scheduling policy:

```
from qiskit.transpiler import PassManager, InstructionDurations
from qiskit.transpiler.passes import  ALAPScheduleAnalysis, PadDelay

# Apply the scheduling policy: 
instruction_durations = InstructionDurations(
    [
        ("h", None, 160),
        ("x", None, 160),
        ("cx", None, 800),
        ("measure", None, 1600),
    ]
)

pass_manager = PassManager(
    [
      ALAPScheduleAnalysis(instruction_durations),
      PadDelay(),
    ]
)
transpiled_circ = pass_manager.run(circ)

# Use DAGCircuit.layers() method with the transpiled circuit:
dag = circuit_to_dag(transpiled_circ)
for layer in dag.layers():
    layer_as_circuit = dag_to_circuit(layer['graph'])
    # Remove the Delay instructions:
    for _inst in layer_as_circuit.data:
      if _inst.operation.name == 'delay':
        layer_as_circuit.data.remove(_inst)
    
    display(layer_as_circuit.draw('mpl'))
```

The result:

[image]

Similarly, you can apply "as soon as possible" ([ASAP](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.transpiler.passes.ASAPScheduleAnalysis.html)) scheduling policy.